# AUTHENTICATE 2 LDAP USER IN ITOPS

Tags: ldap, ldap-query, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have some LDAP users in iTops, and i want to login with all of users in iTops. But i have an error like that "user not found in LDAP".

Which folders that i have to change ? So i can login with all LDAP users.

I appreciate for your responses, all of you. Please help me, thanks.

in config-itop.php

```
$MyModuleSettings = array(
'authent-ldap' => array (
    'host' => '192.168.1.2',
    'port' => 389,
    'default_user' => 'anonim',
    'default_pwd' => 'Admin123',
    'base_dn' => 'dc=vokasiub,dc=COM',
    'user_query' => '(samaccountname=%1$s)',
    'options' => array (
      17 => 3,
      8 => 0,
    ),
    'start_tls' => false,
    'debug' => true,
),
'authent-ldap2' => array (
    'host' => '192.168.2.2',
    'port' => 389,
    'default_user' => 'isoiso',
    'default_pwd' => 'Admin123',
    'base_dn' => 'ou=users ou, dc=bagusyekti,dc=COM',
    'user_query' => '(samaccountname=%1$s)',
    'options' => array (
      17 => 3,
      8 => 0,
    ),
    'start_tls' => false,
    'debug' => true,
),

'itop-attachments' => array (
    'allowed_classes' => array (
      0 => 'Ticket',
    ),
    'position' => 'relations',
    'preview_max_width' => 290,
),
'email-reply' => array (
    'enabled_default' => true,
),
'itop-backup' => array (
    'mysql_bindir' => '',
    'week_days' => 'monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday',
    'time' => '23:30',
    'retention_count' => 5,
    'enabled' => true,
    'debug' => true,
),
```

);

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: 'settings' => array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => 389,
'default_user' => '',
'default_pwd' => '',
'base_dn' => 'dc=yourcompany,dc=com',
'user_query' => '(&(uid=%1$s)(inetuserstatus=ACTIVE))',
'options' => array(
LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION => 3,
LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS => 0,
),
),
)
);
}
?>

Comment: nor send me your email in this comment

Comment: i'm sorry for my late answers, i just check it.

Comment: I meant add your code to your question, not in comments.

Comment: i done to edit my question

Comment: ok, but can i have your contact person ? maybe LINE ID, gmail, or something else ? i need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**iTop 2.7 and older**

This was not possible.

**iTop 3.0 and newer**

This is now possible, check the full documentation [here](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=extensions%3Aauthent-ldap#configuration), but basically you have to set the different LDAP servers like this in the iTop configuration file:

```
'authent-ldap' => array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 389,
        'default_user' => '',
        'default_pwd' => '',
        'base_dn' => 'dc=mycompany,dc=com',
        'user_query' => '(&(uid=%1$s))',
        'options' => array (
                17 => 3,
                8 => 0,
        ),
        'debug' => false,
        'servers' => array(
                'MySecond-LDAP-Server' => array(
                        'host' => 'server1',
                        'port' => 389,
                        'default_user' => '',
                        'default_pwd' => '',
                        'base_dn' => 'dc=mycompany,dc=com',
                        'user_query' => '(&(uid=%1$s))',
                        'options' => array (
                                17 => 3,
                                8 => 0,
                        ),
                        'debug' => false,
                ),
        ),
),
```